# JOINs not giving expected results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables Table F and Table D.

Table F gives details about Financial Transactions of an Account (Payment, Toll, Interest). Table D shows Delinquency Status (if user has not paid into account). It shows different Status Codes. 0, 1, 2, 11 (which mean different things).

My tables structures are as follows:

```
Table F
============
------------------------------------------- 
|AccountId|TypeCode |BusinessDate|TransAmt|
------------------------------------------- 
|12345    | PYMT    |2016-06-22  |   10.54|
------------------------------------------- 
|12345    | TOLL    |2016-06-15  |   04.00|
------------------------------------------- 
|12345    | INTR    |2016-05-26  |   01.66|
------------------------------------------- 
|12345    | TOLL    |2016-04-10  |   04.00|
------------------------------------------- 

Table D
==========
-----------------------------------------------
|AccountId|FromID|ToID|CreatedDate            |
----------------------------------------------- 
|12345    |     0|   2|2016-12-25 00:12:44.453|
----------------------------------------------- 
|12345    |     2|   1|2017-04-02 07:16:46.770|
----------------------------------------------- 
|12345    |     1|  11|2017-07-12 16:16:36.747|
-----------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to run code to find the SUM of all payments made on an account AFTER the Account went into Status Code 11 (ToID)

My code:

```
SELECT F.AccounttID
      ,ISNULL(SUM(TransAmt), 0) Payments

FROM F INNER JOIN D ON F.AccounttID = D.AccountId

WHERE AccountId = 12345   
  AND TypeCode = 'PYMT'   
  AND F.BusinessDate >= D.CreatedDate  
  AND ToID = 11 
--AND F.BusinessDate >= (SELECT CreatedDate FROM D WHERE F.AccounttID = D.AccountId AND ToID = 11)    

GROUP BY F.AccountID, F.TypeCode
```

The results I am getting are:

```
--------------------
|AccountID|Payments|
--------------------
|         |        |
--------------------
```

The results I would like are:

```
--------------------
|AccountID|Payments|
--------------------
|   12345|     0.00|
--------------------
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post yesterday, removing the `group by` is not what you are looking for.  Your `where` criteria is the problem -- it's returning no results.  Because of this you are not getting `0` as the value you want, but rather `null`.  You can use my suggestion of `conditional aggregation` below to get your expected result.  The `outer join` may or may not be helpful as well (I suspect not, but couldn't hurt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is there are no matching results with your `where` criteria.  I think you're actually looking to use `conditional aggregation`.  I've also used an `outer join` in case there's no match:

```
SELECT F.AccounttID
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN F.BusinessDate >= D.CreatedDate THEN F.TransAmt ELSE 0 END) Payments
FROM F 
    LEFT JOIN D ON F.AccounttID = D.AccountId AND D.ToId = 11
WHERE F.AccountId = 12345   
    AND F.TypeCode = 'PYMT'   
GROUP BY F.AccountID
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MAX(F.AccounttID) as AccounttID,
       COALESCE(SUM(TransAmt), 0) Payments
FROM F INNER JOIN
     D
     ON F.AccounttID = D.AccountId
WHERE AccountId = 12345 AND 
      TypeCode = 'PYMT' AND  
      F.BusinessDate >= D.CreatedDate AND
      ToID = 11 
--AND F.BusinessDate >= (SELECT CreatedDate FROM D WHERE F.AccounttID = D.AccountId AND ToID = 11)
```

This may seem counter-intuitive.  But, an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` is guaranteed to return exactly one row, even if all rows are filtered out.  With a `GROUP BY`, an aggregation query returns one row per group.  If all rows are filtered out, then no rows are returned.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. When I used your code, the result I got is: Null  0.00. The result I wanted was 12345  0.00.  Is that possible?